# Why react OnMouseOut isn't working on select option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover, onmouseout

There's an issue with select dropdown box, cause when i scroll down through the items, each item got grey background color (which is normal), but once I removed the mouse from the item to the outside of the dropdown, the last item stayed colored in grey, which is abnormal.

Is there a way to fix this issue, using one of the parameters onmouseleave or onmouseout ?

i tried to use other tags but still not working !!!

Comment: Please, add code or provide a screenshot to improve your question. As I understand it, I would say that the items should highlight ("become grey") on hover (:hover CSS selector), that way you don't have to worry about onmouseleave or onmouseout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.